# How to construct this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert data from this format:

```
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2011, 1, 23), , '<div>Conversation</div><img src="img/comments-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 23, 23, 0, 0), , '<div>Mail from boss</div><img src="img/mail-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 24, 16, 0, 0), , 'Report', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 26), new Date(2011, 2, 2), 'Traject A', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 27), , '<div>Memo</div><img src="img/notes-edit-icon.png" style="width:48px; height:48px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 29), , '<div>Phone call</div><img src="img/Hardware-Mobile-Phone-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 28), new Date(2011, 2, 3), 'Traject B', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0), , '<div>Report</div><img src="img/attachment-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/test-clip-art-cpa-school-test.png', 'test2']
  ]);
```

to:

```
 data.addRows(dataNew);
```

What is the best way to create this array in javascript:

```
[
    [new Date(2011, 1, 23), , '<div>Conversation</div><img src="img/comments-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 23, 23, 0, 0), , '<div>Mail from boss</div><img src="img/mail-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 24, 16, 0, 0), , 'Report', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 26), new Date(2011, 2, 2), 'Traject A', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 27), , '<div>Memo</div><img src="img/notes-edit-icon.png" style="width:48px; height:48px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 29), , '<div>Phone call</div><img src="img/Hardware-Mobile-Phone-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 1, 28), new Date(2011, 2, 3), 'Traject B', '', ''],
    [new Date(2011, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0), , '<div>Report</div><img src="img/attachment-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/test-clip-art-cpa-school-test.png', 'test2']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your array to your variable:

```
var dataNew = [
   [new Date(2011, 1, 23), , '<div>Conversation</div><img src="img/comments-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
   [new Date(2011, 1, 23, 23, 0, 0), , '<div>Mail from boss</div><img src="img/mail-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
   [new Date(2011, 1, 24, 16, 0, 0), , 'Report', '', ''],
   [new Date(2011, 1, 26), new Date(2011, 2, 2), 'Traject A', '', ''],
   [new Date(2011, 1, 27), , '<div>Memo</div><img src="img/notes-edit-icon.png" style="width:48px; height:48px;">', '', ''],
   [new Date(2011, 1, 29), , '<div>Phone call</div><img src="img/Hardware-Mobile-Phone-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', '', ''],
   [new Date(2011, 1, 28), new Date(2011, 2, 3), 'Traject B', '', ''],
   [new Date(2011, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0), , '<div>Report</div><img src="img/attachment-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">', 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/test-clip-art-cpa-school-test.png', 'test2']
];

data.addRows(dataNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the array basics :)

```
var data = [];

data.push(1);
data.push('foo');
data.push(['hello', 'world']);

// data is now: [ 1, 'foo', ['hello', 'world'] ]
```